# The meaning of 管を巻く

Tags: meaning, words, definitions

I stumbled upon this 管を巻く, and looking up, it says that in English, it meant 'to grumble over one's wine cups.' But I still did not understand what it means. Can someone help to explain?

Answer (score 11):

> 「管{くだ}を巻{ま}く」

is an idiomatic expression meaning:

> "to talk incoherently (when drunk)"
>
> "to grumble on and on (when drunk)"

I might add that repeating the same things over and over is often the characteristic of 管を巻く-ing.